# designing redux state tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently in the process of learning Redux, and I've more or less got the hang of the basic concepts. I understand how to work with actions and reducers and all that. What I am struggling with is understanding how to properly design a state tree. I get caught up on the particulars of what should/shouldn't be stored in the application state, when is it acceptable to use component state, the best way to handle state changes, etc.

Are there any good tutorials or blogs out there anyone can recommend for understanding the best practices of designing state?

Comment: I use a ducks pattern https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux and I keep every single piece of state in redux. It's been working well for me so far, and this way I'm 100% sure where my state / errors come from.

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot of differing opinion on this.  Here is what I do.

1. Reducers - hold things that deal with my data model (normally anything that is in a database), that needs to be saved and used later or used across components
2. LocalState (react setState) - deals ui elements in a single component related to user input and interaction

So if i were modeling a response to this question. Redux store would have

```
store = {
  session: { token: 'randomUid' }
  user: { name: 'Austio' }
  question: { id: 37288070 }
}
```

When I select the text box to enter values in to create an answer to this question is would handleInput from this box, which would setState of the answerText.

When is handleSubmit for the form, i would dispatch out based on success something like NEW_ANSWER with the questionId and the answer so that i could store it in the store to be used whereever i need it.

My best advice is to just start programming stuff, it is very difficult to find the edges of your preferences with using redux/react without that.

Comment: "LocalState (react setState) - deals ui elements in a single component related to user input and interaction..."  i've seen people take this approach too, however, i definitely consider that state to be critical as well, and i put it in the store.  form data, what things are highlighted, mouse state, etc--all of it!  debating what goes in state i've observed become a slippery slope.  it can lead to difficulty and reduced a lot of the value redux provides IMHO.  it is easier though!

Comment: Interesting perspective, ultimately do whatever is more natural for you, to me storing local state that does not matter in a global sense makes the app harder to reason about.  I recommend checking out what others think.  Also my perspective is from a frondend team of 8 devs on a pretty large system.  Here is a good discussion https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend checking out Dan Abramov's(creator of Redux) tutorial on egghead.io
https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

He takes you through building a simple todo application, but really emphasizes on the best state building practices throughout the course.